# Drive locked with hdparm during secure erase and power down

Tags: hard-drive, data-corruption

I had the misfortune of trying A LOW LEVEL FORMAT on a *Dell XPS 15z* with a *Toshiba MQ01ABC150* drive without paying full attention. I performed the following:

```
hdparm -I /dev/sda
hdparm --user-master u --security-set-pass llformat /dev/sda
hdparm -I /dev/sda
```

Then something pulled me away from this task long enough for the laptop to go into sleep mode. When I restarted, I got a password prompt for a locked drive! Going into the BIOS confirms the drive password is set by user. I can't boot a liveCD because the drive prompt overrides the BIOS configuration.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

> I had the misfortune of trying A LOW LEVEL FORMAT on a Dell XPS 15z with a Toshiba MQ01ABC150 drive without paying full attention.

Providing a stupid password to hdparm's security-set-pass parameter doesn't make it perform something that relates to *very* old magnetic hard drives¹. The command you left out is usually recommended to erase SSDs. There are still some concerns though if all manufacturers have implemented this feature the right way and that data cannot be recovered from bad blocks which have be replaced with spares by the firmware.

It's funny to see where [cargo cult](https://askubuntu.com/a/498797/40581)² leads to. On a SSD [ATA Secure Erase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write_amplification#Secure_erase) is easy, fast and potentially restores performance (I don't think it will do the impossible thing to reset the cells wear level). To securely erase a slow 1.5 TB HDD every sector of the HDD hat to be rewritten at least once. If you really want to do that have the laptop charger plugged in and disable automatic hibernation or standby then watch it churning for hours. Or mount the drive in a computer you don't need at the moment. That's also how you work around the behavior of your laptop with a locked drive when you can't figure out what to do: mount it in another computer, at worst through an external dock (eSATA or something with SATA hot swap compatibility, I'm not sure if USB supports this feature) while it is already booted.

On the [hdparm](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/hdparm.8.html) manpage you can find a command to unlock a drive and one to disable the password again. Someone else already asked a very [similar question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/q/712849/195746) and accepted an answer, so these commands should work, else you have a nice new paperweight.

To not get cofused by more cargo cult here are the important bits. Unlock ATA password locked drive:

```
hdparm --user-master m --security-unlock PASS DEVICE
```

Disable ATA security password:

```
hdparm --user-master m --security-disable PASS DEVICE
```

---

1. This a probably another terrible comparison, but low level formating a HDD in times long past meant providing particular information to the drive to have it operate normally and then format it, like you would tell a SSD that it has a particular layout of storage (how many cells of SLC, MLC and/or TLC, V-NAND, what kind of redundancy, spare blocks, how the addressing and cache algorithms should work etc.). *That* is the level of blatant stupidity when users talk about low level formatting storage devices with controllers these days who obviously out smart themselves by several orders of magnitude.
2. I just made an edit to the answer here on AskUbuntu which will hopefully clear up some confusion. I saw this question and answer in my feed reader the past days and wondered about the terribly misleading password myself.